# In physics, what is the difference between a fact and a definition?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, definition

For example, I came across this statement:

> "It is a fact that the components of force are derivatives of potential energy, but it is not a definition."

What does this statement mean?
I know that we can't always find a function $V(x)$ in which:
$$F_i(\{x\})=-\frac{\partial V(\{x\})}{\partial x_i}$$
Does the statement have to do with this equation?

Comment: This only applies to conservative forces, not all forces

Comment: *I know that we can't find…* Why do you think that? We *can* find such a $V$ if the force is conservative.

Comment: What is the difference between $V(x)$ and $V(\{x\})$?

Comment: *What is the difference between a fact and a definition?* Do you think that all the facts you know, like “The Earth is approximately spherical” are just *definitions*? What is being defined there? Earth? Spherical?

Comment: Came across where? Which page?

Comment: I’m voting to close this post (v2) because the title question seems not about physics. Moreover, the given example seems not particularly illustrative of the title question.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a physics question - I have edited the question to make this even more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definition is always true.  I define a=1.   Within the context of what I’m doing a is always 1

A fact, is something that agrees with experience.

Answer (score 1):

In physics, as with all of the natural sciences, facts are those things which are established through the *scientific method*. In this sense, the sciences are intrinsically *empirical* in their epistemic outlook. Definitions are concepts that have been described, delineated or otherwise set apart so that individuals can agree, hopefully unambiguously, on their meaning. Definitions are important to the sciences because without them it is difficult to form a hypothesis, or to make a measurement. For example, in order to measure the speed of an object one must first make an *operational definition* which enables one to undertake the necessary steps in performing the observation.

Essentially, the statement that: we cannot always find a function $V(x)$ such that $$F_i(x)={\partial V(x)\over\partial x_i},$$ is a statement affirming that not all forces in nature are conservative. The validity of this statement hangs on the definition of a conservative force as a force that has components given by the gradient of some scalar function of the coordinates. In particular, non-conservative forces are not *defined* as such. Attempts at such a neat definition of non-conservative forces have been made, an example of which is the *Raleigh's dissipation function* for certain dissipative forces that can be modeled as:
$$F_i=-{\partial\over\partial v_i}\mathcal F(\vec v).$$ However, not all non-conservative forces fit into so neat a category, and indeed, they need not be derivable from a scalar function at all.